# What is the 'Book of David'?

Tags: islam, david

What is the *Book of David* and is it part of the Bible? In Islam we know it as Zaboor (زبور). Is it available today?

Comment: well, what is the main message of this book, so that we could recognise it? The *character* David is mentioned in Samuel, 1 Kings, and 1 Chronicles - I wonder if this is a re-structuring of those, perhaps.

Comment: it is a holey book like bible and Torah and contains many messages. one message is: the earth will be inherited by good slaves of God. generally it is the book revealed to prophet David PBUH.

Comment: It may refer to the book of Psalms, which in large part is attributed to David.

Comment: We do welcome questions about Christianity, but some level of prior research is expected (this is actually true of most SE sites as they are expert oriented). The Wikipedia articles in English, Arabic and Farsi on the Zabur cover it's likely being a reference to the book of Psalms from the Bible within the first two lines, as do the top results from Google.

Comment: General Reference / LMGTFY question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no absolute agreement about what the [Book of David (Zaboor or Zabur)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabur) is referring to. The majority opinion is that it refers to the [Book of Psalms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms), which is a part of the Bible. The majority of the Psalms are traditionally written by David.

Comment: thanks. I was not aware of book Psalms. where I can read it? I heard David PBUH had wonderful Judgements.

Comment: [Here](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+1&version=NIV) is probably a good place to start (that's the English - you can select other languages). Or any Bible will contain it.

Comment: I would suggest you start with Psalm 23 first, Psalm 1 next, and then Psalm 22. They are all written by David. These are three of the most well known.  Psalms is like a songbook, so one doesn't lead into the other.  That's not true of other books, however...

Answer (score 5):

David was not the *sole* author of any books of the Bible, but:

1. He authored most (but not all) of the Psalms, a Jewish Hymnbook that is the Largest book of the Bible.
2. He is the primary character in the second half of 1 Samuel and all of 2 Samuel, plus its duplicate 1 Chronicles.

According to this [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_holy_books), the Books of David are often assumed to be the Psalms, but are not so universally held.  Likewise, the Books of Isa are often assumed to be the New Testament, but could refer to an unknown Gospel authored by Jesus himself.  In any event, these are not canonical books.

A better understanding of the Islamic views on these books would of course be found on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/), but you'd know that :)

Answer (score -1):

Every Ethiopian Orthodox priest starts with the study of the book of David, my father being one of them. It's available in Ethiopia but it's in [Ge'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_language), an almost extinct language now used solely by the Ethiopian Orthodox church.

I have not heard of any translations but I know a tiny bit of the language and it is strictly structured for the Bible: Every word and character is built around the Bible so when it gets translated things might get lost in translation and as every one knows is very very dangerous.

Comment: Can you please take some time when you write to follow [standard rules for English capitalization](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/10-rules-of-capitalization.html)? It would make your posts a lot easier to read and we do have an expectation here that posts are to be more scholarly than you might otherwise use in informal settings. Think of them as short essays that you are turning in for a grade, not FB posts to your friends.

Comment: @Michael Tell us more about this book in Ethiopia. Do you know what the contents are about? Does it have anything to do with the David of the Jewish Scriptures?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)